# How to change column values to rows in Excel with PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

For some testing I do for work, a CSV file is created with the numbers all on one row, but a lot of columns. I need all these numbers added together and then divided by the number of columns. When you open Excel and select all, excel already gives you an average.

However, I want to do this automated in PowerShell and so far I haven't been able to do just this. I was able to get an average of values that were in rows, so my question would be either one of these:

1: How can I calculate the average from all columns that have a value?
or,
2: How can I get the values from the columns in rows instead of columns?

From another CSV file, that I do get correctly, I currently use this code to get the average value over a total of 1500 rows.

```
Import-Csv "$test.csv" | Select 'Frame time' -First 1500 | Measure-object 'Frame time' -ave | Select-Object -expand Average
```

One more question would be, is there a way to make a calculation with the value that is returned, instead of typing it over and putting it in a calculation as a variable?

I'm fairly new to PowerShell scripting, and I find these kind of actions pretty difficult (to find).

Comment: So you want the average of all numbers in the csv? The csv contains only numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you just have a csv full of numbers then instead of using `Import-CSV` you could just use `Get-Content` to read the file and extract all the numbers that are present. Consider the following input

```
column1,column2,column3,column4
2,4,6,8
1,2,3,4
5,10,15,20
```

You could do something like this

```
Get-Content C:\temp\names.csv | 
    Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
    ForEach-Object{$_.Split(",")} | 
    Measure-Object -Average | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average
```

Read the file as an array of strings. `Select-Object -Skip 1` is optional and dependent on the presence of a header in your file. If you do not have one then remove the line. Then for each line split it up on the `,`. All of that output is sent to `Measure-Object` to calculate the average. Then, we use `Select-Object` to break the value out of the object and just return the data.

On that note if you want the result to use for later then you just need to capture it in a variable.

```
 $result = Get-Content C:\temp\names.csv | 
    Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
    ForEach-Object{$_.Split(",")} | 
    Measure-Object -Average | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average
```